# Using setInterval or requestAnimationFrame for moving SVG circle on a path

Tags: html, svg

Hi all so I was working on an assignment and completely at the fault of my own I didn't see that my professor wanted me to use setInterval or requestAnimationFrame as part of the solution.
Basically we have to create a circle on an SVG canvas, then when the user clicks a button it will make the circle follow a path infinitely. I got it working only to find out I did it wrong. I'm pretty new and bad at coding right now so any help would be appreciated. This is a link to the actual webpage that I had uploaded.
http://obsidian.sru.edu/users/btw1004/CPSC337/hw06.html

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Rotate</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
            svg {
                border: 1px solid blue;
            }
            circle {
                animation-iteration-count: infinite;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            //Brandon Wong, Oct 14 2020
            function moveCir() {
                //Appends existing begin attribute
                document.getElementById("animCir").setAttribute("begin", "0s");
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Brandon Wong</h1>
        <svg width="800" height="800">
            <defs>
                <path id="cb1" d="M 0 0 
                a 200,200 0 1,0 400,0
                a 200,200 0 1,0 -400,0 "/>
            </defs>
            <circle id="cir1" 
            cx="200" cy="400" r="30"
            style="fill: yellow; stroke: black;">
            <animateMotion id="animCir"
            begin=""
            dur="4s" 
            repeatCount="indefinite">
                <mpath href="#cb1"/>
            </animateMotion>
            </circle>
        </svg>
        <button onclick="moveCir()">Rotate</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Again sorry if it looks very trashy or unorganized, I'm still trying to figure this out and I'm not too good at it.

edit:
Assignment Desc
(3)Place a circle on the SVG canvas and a button below the canvas.If the user clicks the button, the circle starts to rotate along a circular pathinfinitely. You decide the size, formatting of the circle, the location of circular path, initial location of the circle, and the speed of rotation;
(4)The animation needs to be done by modifying the location of SVG circle objectin JavaScript code. The code can callsetInterval()to starta periodic timerto update the circle's location, or can callrequestAnimationFrame()to tell the browser to update the circle's locationwith a function call (here is the reference webpage on requestAnimationFrame():https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Comment: Could you also post the assignment description?

Comment: I just added it

Comment: I have answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You implementation is legit except it doesn't meet the requirement that `requestAnimationFrame` or `setInterval` API must be used.

I'll go with `requestAnimationFrame`. Refer to the [doc and example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame), `requestAnimationFrame(step)` takes as argument a `step` function. The key is to calculate and update, within the `step()` function, the `(x, y)` coordinates of the position of that yellow dot for each animation frame.

Refresh our memory about the [Parametric Equation of a Circle](https://www.mathopenref.com/coordparamcircle.html).  `x = r * cos(t); y = r * sin(t)`. In your case `r = 200`, and `t` the theta angle goes from 0 to 2π in 4 seconds.

Here's the `step(timestamp)` function. It is passed the `timestamp` of current animation frame at each call.

```js
const FOUR_SECONDS_IN_MS = 4 * 1000;
let start;
function step(timestamp) {
  if (!start) start = timestamp;
  const elapse = timestamp - start;
  const fraction = elapse / FOUR_SECONDS_IN_MS;
  const t = fraction * 2 * Math.PI;
  const r = 200;
  const x = r * Math.cos(t);
  const y = r * Math.sin(t);
  const circle = document.getElementById('cir1');
  circle.setAttribute('cx', x);
  circle.setAttribute('cy', y);
}
```

Above is the gist of the idea.

But in your case the center of the circle is `(400, 400)` not `(0, 0)`, and the `t` angle parameter, which decides the position of yellow dot, starts at `π` not `0`, we need to apply those offsets accordingly. Plus, we need to recursively call `requestAnimationFrame(step)` inside `step` function so the animation can go on looping.

We modify above formula to:

```js
const FOUR_SECONDS_IN_MS = 4 * 1000
let start;

function step(timestamp) {
  if (!start) start = timestamp;
  const elapse = timestamp - start;
  const fraction = elapse / FOUR_SECONDS_IN_MS;
  const t = fraction * 2 * Math.PI + Math.PI; // offset t
  const r = 200;
  const x = r * Math.cos(t) + 400; // offset x
  const y = r * Math.sin(t) + 400; // offset y
  const circle = document.getElementById('cir1');
  circle.setAttribute('cx', x);
  circle.setAttribute('cy', y);
  // recursive call:
  requestAnimationFrame(step);
}

function startAnimation() {
  requestAnimationFrame(step);
}
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<svg width="800" height="800">
    <circle id="cir1"
      cx="200" cy="400" r="30"
      style="fill: yellow; stroke: black;">
    </circle>
</svg>
<button onclick="startAnimation()">Rotate</button>
```

Comment: Sorry for the long response, I’m still kinda learning how to use this site. I’ll give this a try later but I appreciate your help very much!

Comment: No problem. See if anything unclear you can comment and @me I can further explain. When you feel content with my answer, please accept it (by clicking the check mark beneath up/down arrows).

Comment: Thank you so much, this is working perfectly now and it makes sense. It doesn't seem like it's that difficult, I think I just needed it broken down a little bit.